TypeError in imblearn pipeline: type 'Pipeline' is not subscriptable
transform = [("ord", OrdinalEncoder(), ['job', 'education']),
             ("ohe", OneHotEncoder(), ['contact', 'month', 'poutcome'])]

ct = ColumnTransformer(transform, remainder='passthrough')

p = imbpipeline[('ct', ct),
                ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                ('smote', SMOTE(random_state=0)),
                ('xgb', XGBClassifier())]

While trying to run the above I am getting error
"TypeError: type 'Pipeline' is not subscriptable"


I'm quite sure this is not a valid syntax. Square brackets with multiple tuples inside?

Hello @Nishant Padhee! Did my answer help you? If so, I'd appreciate if you could accept it
